# How can I put Google Drive API files.list requests for different users in the same batch request?

Tags: google-drive-api

Normally, one would use `BatchHttpRequest` to aggregate several requests, but what if I want to list files for two different users?

Nominally that requires an oauth2 token per-user.  `BatchHttpRequest` either takes one `http` object (which handles the credentials) for the batch, or pulls it out of the first batched request encountered when `.execute()` is called.

Using oauth1 to sign each batched requests results in proper results (different feeds for each user).  However, using oauth2 and manually constructing the payload results in identical feeds (matching the user in the first batched request):

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=blah
Content-Length: 572
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache

--blah
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <b29c5de2-0db4-490b-b421-6a51b598bd22+1>

GET /drive/v2/changes HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ya29.UQAabvlG2hnRPyEAAADUm7vkDe_qg7L49R655IyxvgBnkN7_PEgE3IG7UnZ_ZEmJwUK_6fSV4kTHjNQIjTk
accept: application/json
--blah
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <b29c5de2-0db4-490b-b421-6a51b598bd22+2>

GET /drive/v2/changes HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ya29.UQBu8f9W8S5E6RwAAAAPqCOiqoFW3QEFYkBvQGx36UVKNHeEhdZT8GPN-P74ng
accept: application/json
--blah
```

Since oauth1 works, it seems that this is at least theoretically possible, although I may be blocked by a google bug where the oauth2 token for the first request in the batch overrides any other authorizations included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google-provided client does not support this, but providing an `Authorization` header for each request will work.  The example given should work assuming all of the authorization header values are correct.